# Send mail from HTML form with PHP backend

Tags: php, html, email

I am working on my personal website at the moment, and I have done everything, except when a message comes through from a user via the contact form, and email is successfully sent to me, but the content contained within said email is blank.

My code is below:

**PHP (sendmail.php)**

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/json');
$status = array(
    'type'=>'success',
    'message'=>'Your email has been succesfully sent.'
);

$name = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['name'])); 
$email = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['email'])); 
$subject = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['subject'])); 
$message = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['message'])); 

$email_from = $email;
$email_to = 'me@joshuaquinlan.co.uk';

$body = 'Name: ' . $name . "\n\n" . 'Email: ' . $email . "\n\n" . 'Subject: ' . $subject . "\n\n" . 'Message: ' . $message;

$success = @mail($email_to, $subject, $body, 'From: <'.$email_from.'>');

echo json_encode($status);
die;
```

**HTML (contact-us.html):**

```
<form id="main-contact-form" class="contact-form" name="contact-form" method="post" action="sendmail.php" role="form">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-5">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" required="required" placeholder="Full Name">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control" required="required" placeholder="Email address">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" name="subject" class="form-control" required="required" placeholder="Subject">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Send Message</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-7">
        <textarea name="message" id="message" required="required" class="form-control" rows="8" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
    </div>
</div>
```

When the email is actually sent, however, it actually shows up like 
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m5fJc.png)

Please, if someone can help me, then thank you!

Comment: When trying to diagnose errors, using the error suppression operator *might* not be the best idea...

Comment: Why do you need `stripslashes()`? Remove it.

Comment: Try to include another value for testing: ```$debug = print_r($_REQUEST, true);``` 
Maybe this gives some more insight. Right now I would say the code should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is you are **not sending anything** from your form:

```
$.post($(this).attr('action'),function(data){$this.prev().text(data.message) // ...
```

You forgot to add the data:

```
$.post($(this).attr('action'),$(this).serialize(), function(data){$this.prev().text(data.message) // ...
```

**Beautified Code**

```
// You forgot to add data here v----
$.post($(this).attr('action'), function(data) {
  $this.prev().text(data.message).fadeIn().delay(3000).fadeOut();
}, 'json');
```

So correct it to:

```
// added data using serialize() vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
$.post($(this).attr('action'), $(this).serialize(), function(data) {
  $this.prev().text(data.message).fadeIn().delay(3000).fadeOut();
}, 'json');
```

**Find and Replace**

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> (Replace).
2. Paste this in **Find For**: `$.post($(this).attr('action'),func`.
3. Paste this in **Replace With**: `$.post($(this).attr('action'),$(this).serialize(),func`.
4. Press <kbd>Replace</kbd>.
5. See below screenshot for more details.

**Screenshot**

[image]